# ASUS N550JV screen turns 'reddish' after Windows boots

Tags: windows-8, laptop, graphics-card, display

So, my [ASUS N550JV](http://www.asus.com/Notebooks_Ultrabooks/N550JV/) is brand new. There is a strange issue of screen turning 'reddish' after a while following the Windows 8 boot-up.

[image: normal screen]
[image]

This actually happens in two scenarios:

- After the startup programs load up, i.e. disk usage calms down from 100%
- When I plug out the HDMI cable (TV). The screen goes to normal colors when TV is joined to displaying (duplicate screens), but when I plug it off, the screen turns reddish.

---

**An Extreme Scenario**

I booted a [Linux distro for anti-virus purposes](https://support.kaspersky.com/8092) from USB drive after disabling secure boot and enabling CSM in UEFI. Everything was normal. Then I rebooted the system. This time (I tried to boot Linux), the screen was black and fans went crazy (louder than in a CPU stress test) and then I got my battery light flashing on the front side of the laptop. Now that I'm back to my original OS (Win8), my battery was draining but when I plugged it in, it did not charge. However, my screen was normal! Never went red again, until I updated the UEFI which fixed my battery problem and gave me back the red screen.

---

**What I tried?**

I took screenshots before the startup processes finished and after the screen turned reddish. Both appeared the same.

I updated both of my drivers: Intel HD Graphics 4600 and NVIDIA GeForce GT 750M. I know when powerful graphics processing is needed, NVIDIA is used so I suspect the Intel Graphics is the problem since only rendering the graphical interface is carried out. So, I went to Intel Graphics' Control Panel's Display Tab and played with 'red color's enhancement' values. This seems to fix it. Although when I extend the displays, the reddish screen stays on laptop and normal colors are displayed on TV, as I said before changing enhancement values fixes the problem.

Note: I had another ASUS N550JV before I replaced it with this one and it did not have such a problem. So this is specific to this device.

## The question is:

What would trigger such an issue? How is BIOS related to this? **Is there any other fix to this other than changing the red enhancement value?** I ask for another fix because this is simply a workaround, not a complete solution to the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a hardware fault to me, or perhaps a low-level firmware problem. Either way, your machine that you paid money for shouldn't have this issue.

It's possible to still be a software matter, perhaps due to some very new hardware in there that's poorly supported? Did you try updating your motherboard's firmware (bios/efi)?

You could try booting a different Linux distro, such as Ubuntu, just in case the one you tried had some very poor hardware support.

If it were me, I wouldn't put much more effort in before calling up ASUS.

Comment: I wiped everything clean, installed a Windows 8.1. Problem gone, which, I think, concludes a driver problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is a utility called Asus splendid video which is culprit for reddish colour .I myself faced the problem then i uninstalled this utility from control panel and it was solved.

Comment: I'm loathe to edit in details but this makes sense. I'd guess its using a different set of colour settings/temperature when an external output is used. It wouldn't be necessary to uninstall it, merely to change the settings in use.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 10, if this only happens after sunset and before sunrise, then it's due to *night light*. It's actually desirable then, unless you want to stay up the entire night. Lack of blue light helps with keeping our day-night cycle in the "night" mode. I realize that this wasn't the source of the problem back in 2014, but today the first culprit would be *night light*, and then it's a good thing. Night light sometimes doesn't turn off in the morning (seems to be a software glitch), you can then turn it off manually. Press the Windows key, type *night*, select *night light* from the list, press Enter, and you'll be taken to the night light Settings page, where you can turn it off until sundown.